# Guided Grad-CAM visualization, weighting of gradients

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, visualization

I implemented Grad-CAM and Guided Backprop as presented in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391) and everything is working as expected. The next step is to combine the class activation map and the gradient map to get the final weighted gradients. In the paper this is done by point-wise multiplication:

> In order to combine the best aspects of both, we fuse Guided Backpropagation and Grad-CAM visualizations via pointwise multiplication (Grad-CAM is first up-sampled to the input image resolution using bi-linear interpolation)

The corresponding figure (cropped) is:

[image]

My problem is as follows: The class activation map contains mostly 0's, i.e. the blue regions, which will produce 0's when multiplied with the gradients. However, in the image the guided grad-cam map is mostly grey.

I'm aware that the grey area in the gradient map is due to the gradients being 0 in most places and normalization to the range [0,1] will put them somewhere around 0.5 (assuming that we have both positive and negative gradients with a similar magnitude). Still, multiplication with 0 will result in 0, which should be displayed as black.

For comparison my maps look like this:

[image]

Can anyone explain what operation is used to combine both maps? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All assumptions are correct. The thing I was missing is that in the case of guided Grad-CAM  the weighting of the gradients is done before the normalization to the range [0,1].